# how can i run url in without including id in Angular2 .like /edit/:id

Tags: angular

I need browser url

http://192.168.0.115:8000/#/store/order/detail

insted of this url

http://192.168.0.115:8000/#/store/order/detail/58f4a9140ee8bd1130378937

and view or edit detail of particular id in AngularJS 2

Answer (score 0):

it is not supported at this moment. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10248. I would create a wrapper around route navigate call for such situations and push the id into a common service or ngrx.